# NFS keeps randomly crashing, breaks mount on other clients

Tags: ubuntu, nfs

I interconnect several of my Linux servers with NFS. For a while its been going fine but for some reason keeps getting more and more unstable

Example: Copy a 4 GB file from client to NFS server, fails before finishing with an IO error. `dmesg` is filled with

```
[1525450.884071] nfs: server quackron not responding, timed out
[1525451.384072] nfs: server quackron not responding, timed out
[1525451.884072] nfs: server quackron not responding, timed out
[1525452.384086] nfs: server quackron not responding, timed out
[1525452.884065] nfs: server quackron not responding, timed out
[1525584.112127] nfs: server quackron not responding, timed out
[1525669.492066] nfs: server quackron not responding, timed out
[1525930.544062] nfs: server quackron not responding, timed out
```

Mount options (the many extra options are to prevent a disappearing NFS server from locking the whole directory until a restart or umount trickery)

```
rw,intr,soft,timeo=5,retrans=5,actimeo=10,retry=5,vers=4,addr=10.0.0.20,clientaddr=10.0.0.1
```

Going to the server, I get this in dmesg

```
[1384141.237197] NFSD: Using /var/lib/nfs/v4recovery as the NFSv4 state recovery directory
[1384141.237237] NFSD: starting 90-second grace period
[1439491.137710] nfsd: last server has exited, flushing export cache
[1439492.461197] NFSD: Using /var/lib/nfs/v4recovery as the NFSv4 state recovery directory
[1439492.461236] NFSD: starting 90-second grace period
```

I can't find it in this dmesg or the log, but I do know I've seen "nfsd last server has exited signal 15" errors. Googling can't seem to find any useful information

Any idea's what would cause nfs to constantly crash?

Note: This server is running Ubuntu Server 11.10 and is fully up to date

Comment: Have you tried `scp` to copy the same file?

Comment: @Karlson Just tried it. Works perfectly fine. Right afterwards tried NFS just crashed again

Comment: @TheLQ - Please input the defined NFS export from /etc/exports.

Comment: Its not in `/etc/exports`, its mounted in a script for various reasons. Script command: `sudo mount -t nfs -o intr,soft,timeo=5,retrans=5,actimeo=10,retry=5 -v -v -v $1:$2 $3` with the variables at the end corresponding to server, remote folder, and local folder

Comment: is this on 32 or on 64 bits ?

Comment: can you try the `async` option ? It can help for large files transfer.

Comment: @Coren Server is 64-bit, Client is 32-bit. And isn't `async` a little dangerous with only cosmetic performance benefits?

Comment: @TheLQ It looks like a 32bit int overflow, ie a bug, especially if it works well with file under 2 GB.

Comment: If NFS is that troublesome and scp works without problem - use sshfs.

Comment: @TheLQ: Are you saying that it is not in the exports on the NFS server? If you are not exporting the drive, volume, or whatever to an IP, subnet, or network then how are you able to access it?

Comment: @LinuxlyChallenged Well apparently I've been reading that as `/etc/fstab`, not `/etc/exports`. Here's the relevant line: `/home/lordquackstar *(rw,sync,no_subtree_check)`

Comment: @TheLQ can you modify your `mount` on the client side to: `sudo mount -t nfs -o intr,hard,timeo=14,rsize=8192,wsize=8192` or if you put it in `fstab` on the client side `remoteserver:/remote/path /local/path nfs rsize=8192,wsize=8192,hard,time0=14,intr 0 0` as a test. I use these settings at work and we routinely transfer several TB a week. Use these settings adding none of the others except for your specific pathing variables.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As a test, modify your mount on the client side to:

```
sudo mount -t nfs -o intr,hard,timeo=14,rsize=8192,wsize=8192
```

or, if you put it in `fstab` on the client side:

```
remoteserver:/remote/path /local/path nfs rsize=8192,wsize=8192,hard,timeo=14,intr 0 0
```

I use these settings at work and we routinely transfer several TB a week.

Use these settings adding none of the others except for your specific pathing variables.

Comment: Just did some testing, seems to of fixed the problem! Connection is stable enough to copy a 3.6 GB ISO without disconnecting. Seems to even be a bit faster, although I'm not for sure. Thanks!

Comment: Awesome!! You can play with the `rsize` and `wsize` this modifies the data transfer buffer sizes. The only thing you need to worry about is your network setup as it relates to `MTU` I have never had an issue but, others have. Without going and looking I think you can go up to 32,xxx for them.

Comment: Does anyone have an idea what is actually causing this issue? The default NFS mounting set `hard`, negotiate `rsize` and `wsize` to max value. Is it because of `intr`? Or it is because of a much smaller `timeo` time (1.4s compared to default 60s).

Answer (score 0):

If it's a dedicated NFS VLAN, double check you don't have any duplicate IPs on your network.  I just debugged an issue very much like this, and it turns out there were some typos in kickstart files and out of 40 hosts, we had 5 that were using duplicate IP addresses.   NFS would work great and copies would be fast for a while, but performance would gradually taper off, then hang altogether.

Comment: Went ahead and verified that there was no duplicate IP's, couldn't find any